# error with p4merge merging tool in git

Tags: git, p4merge

I have setup my classpath for p4merge an set the file .gitconfig, but there i get this error when the p4merge tool suppose to opem those two files that are in conflict. anybody knows the solution?

added to classpath: "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe"
added to .gitconfig file:

```
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = p4merge.exe \\\"$BASE\\\" \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\" \\\"$MERGED\\\"
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Normal merge conflict for 'protected/views/layouts/main.php':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (p4merge):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/mergetools/p4merge: line 8: p4merge:
 command not found
protected/views/layouts/main.php seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] n
merge of protected/views/layouts/main.php failed
```

Answer (score 6):

It works for me:

```
[merge]
    keepBackup = false;
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
```

Comment: `keepTemporaries `by default is false. In any case, it should be set as `mergetool.keepTemporaries`, not `mergetool.<Tool>.keepTemporaries`.  `KeepBackup` is also set without specifying `<Tool>`.

Comment: `trustExitCode` shouldn't be set to false (it should be default - true).

Answer (score 4):

Why is everything so hard I hate to write commands so what I did?

1. Install p4Merge tool form [here](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix#product-10) 
   serach for P4Merge and install the exe then you need only

[image]

2. Install it as Windows user
3. Go into your user direcotry and search for **.gitconfig** edit it and add

> ```
> [mergetool "p4merge"]
>   path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
>   cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
> [merge]
>   tool = p4merge
> ```

How to use it? When you pull something and have conflicts you can just write

> git mergetool

And the tool will be open.

[image]

At the bottom is you final version you can edit there then just save and commit and the conflict will be resolved.

Comment: The option `path` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to restart your git console if you've just installed p4merge, for the updated environment variables to register.

Answer (score 2):

After I installaed P4Merge, I followed the instructions on this page and it works perfectly for me.

https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372

Comment: Too bad it's for OSX and the OP is clearly on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it can't find p4merge so try adding "C:\Program Files\Perforce\" to your PATH environment variable via System Properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you don`t want to add p4merge in environmental variable Path (as Dan Lister mentioned) you could add parameter path in your git config:

```
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
```

It works for me on git v1.7.11 (WinXP).

Comment: I don't like tabs order REMOTE, BASE, LOCAL. It's better to use
`cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe' $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED`

Answer (score 0):

Add the full P4merge path to your .gitconfig. Here's mine (note that the path separators are flipped around, i.e. c:/ instead of c:\):

```
[merge]
    tool = p4
[mergetool "p4"]
    cmd = c:/winprogs/p4merge/p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Comment: If path to the exe contains spaces then it should be in quotes.
`cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe' $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED`

Answer (score 0):

```
These steps worked for me.
```

After downloading and installing P4Merge tool from perforce.com

After your profile name/email id.

Replace this content in your ~/.gitconfig file

```
 enter code here

[merge]
  keepBackup = false
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "\"$PWD/$BASE\"" "\"$PWD/$LOCAL\""  "\"$PWD/$REMOTE\"" "\"$PWD/$MERGED\""   
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge "\"$REMOTE\"" "\"$LOCAL\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the proper set up as merge tool.

- $ git config --global merge.tool p4mergetool
- $ git config --global mergetool.p4mergetool.cmd \
  "/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge \$PWD/\$BASE \$PWD/\$REMOTE \$PWD/\$LOCAL \$PWD/\$MERGED"
- $ git config --global mergetool.p4mergetool.trustExitCode false
- $ git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false

Reference: https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372

Answer (score 0):

1) edit your git config file

```
git config --edit --global
```

2) add following (change accordingly)

```
[merge]
    keepBackup = false;
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
[diff]
    tool = p4mergetool
[difftool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge $LOCAL $REMOTEhere
```

3) initialize the config file

```
git init
```

All set, you are ready to go.